# Make attributes incompatible with each other?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

Is there a simple way to make my attributes incompatible with each other? C# .net

Comment: You want the code not to compile if two attributes are used?

Comment: I believe that is the case - it sounds like he want to create two or more attributes that are mutually exclusive. For example [IsCat], [IsDog] and [IsHamster] attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  You could combine them into a single attribute that takes a non-flag enum...

Comment: And don't forget to set `AllowMultiple = false`

Comment: gotta love one liner questions, answers and great one liner comment(s) ;D